# Pure CSS Dropdown menu - border overwrite

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I am try to have border around the menu and the submenu, and wrap them inside a box.

I am trying to use a white border bottom on the top menu to overwrite the border on the sub menu, to give it more visual look.

The problem is that I do not see the "white bottom border on the top menu" overwrite the "the top border in the submenu". I have added z-index to it, and it does not solve the problem.

Please code is at:http://jsfiddle.net/fjfhan4L/

```
<h2 style="clear:both;">Menu 6 (clean up)</h2>
<nav class="menu-6">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li style="float:none; clear:both;"></li>
    </ul>
</nav> 

   nav.menu-6 ul{
    list-style:none;
}

nav.menu-6 > ul{
    background-color: yellow;
}

nav.menu-6 a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav.menu-6 > ul > li{
    float:left;
    padding-right: 100px;
    display: relative;
}

nav.menu-6 > ul > li > a{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
}

nav.menu-6 > ul > li:hover > a{
    border: solid #000 1px;
    border-bottom: solid #fff 1px;     /* overwrite the sub menu top border */ 
}   

nav.menu-6 ul li > ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    border: solid #000 1px;
    z-index: 1;
}

nav.menu-6 > ul > li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: result: http://jsfiddle.net/0ngbxogg/

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
nav.menu-6 ul li > ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
border: solid #000 1px;
z-index: 1;
margin-top: -1px; /* this is all you're adding to the css */
```

}

You just need to add "margin-top: -1px" to the above css and it should fix your problem. I didn't check it on multiple browsers, but it worked on your provided fiddle, at least if I'm correct in what you're looking for in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `border-bottom`to overwrite the other border use the `:before` psuedo element:

**HTML**

```
<h2 style="clear:both;">Menu 6 (clean up)</h2>
    <nav class="menu-6">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        <li style="float:none; clear:both;"></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav.menu-6 ul{
    list-style:none;
}

nav.menu-6 > ul{
    background-color: yellow;
}

nav.menu-6 a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav.menu-6 > ul > li{
    float:left;
    padding-right: 100px;
    display: relative;
}

nav.menu-6 > ul > li > a{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
}

/* Set parent element relative */
nav.menu-6 > ul > li a { position:relative;} 

/* before element */  
nav.menu-6 > ul > li a:after { position:absolute; content:""; width:100%;             height:1px; left:0; bottom:-2px; opacity:0; z-index:9999; background:#fff;}
nav.menu-6 > ul > li:hover a:after { opacity:1;}

nav.menu-6 > ul > li:hover > a{
    border: solid #000 1px;
}   

nav.menu-6 ul li > ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    border: solid #000 1px;
    z-index: 1;
}

nav.menu-6 > ul > li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}
```

Check out fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ggChris/hebhrd8o/